# is there any Benchmarking tool for available for testing SQL server CE?

Tags: sql, sql-server

HI , is there any Benchmarking tool available for testing SQL server CE ?

Answer (score 0):

The device that the server runs on will largely determine the results, rather than the SQL Server CE instance itself. Is this on a desktop machine, a server, or a phone?

If you were to start a benchmark yourself, consider a few questions:

- What are the performance metrics that you're concerned with? A heavy focus on writes, reads, or an even balance?
- What aspects are you interested in testing? Disk access, indexing, CPU usage under writes or reads?

Comment: The device will be running on a very low configuration system which has xp ,500MHZ ..I want to test or benchmark all aspect like read,writes ,CPU usage or Hardware performance....